# Custom Yii2 TimestampBehavior

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

I have behavior in my model

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',
            // 'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
        ],
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'updated_at',
            'value' => time(),
        ],
    ]; 
}
```

Everything is working. But I need that only in one action does not work.
It is necessary that in actionView did not change "update_at" attribute. My actionView:

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
$model->views++;
$model->save();
```

How can I do this as correctly as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$model->save(false, ['views']);
```

First parameter determines if validation should run (for this example it's not necessary), second determines attributes which should be saved.

[Yii2 ActiveRecord - save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail) or [Yii2 ActiveRecord - updateCounters()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#updateCounters()-detail) (which is better)

Comment: In db "updated_at" does not change. But in view(render) still changing attribute "update_at".

Comment: `$model->refresh()` after save

Answer (score 1):

You may just update it with special method [ActiveRecord::updateCounters()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#updateCounters()-detail).

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
// Don't forget to check whether the model is null
if ($model !== null) {
    $model->updateCounters(['views' => 1]);
}
```